# "The assignment expression type [java.lang.Object] did not match the assignment path type" after springboot version upgrade

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We have entity class defined with the following field:

```
@Column
private LocalDateTime updatedDate;
```

and the following function created:

```
create function now_utc() returns timestamp without time zone
    language sql
as
$$
  select now() at time zone 'utc';
$$;
```

We are working on springboot version updated and got the following error

org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: The assignment expression type [java.lang.Object] did not match the assignment path type [] for the path [alias_1370160613.updatedDate]

There are a lot of suggestions how to fix it but nothing works. Can it be because of specific version of postgresql + springboot + hibernate ?

springboot version is 3.1.6

hibernate version is 6.2.13

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html

> Migration guide
>
> Instant mapping changes Instant now maps to the type code
> SqlType.TIMESTAMP_UTC by default, which maps to the SQL type timestamp
> with time zone if possible, and falls back to timestamp. Due to this
> change, schema validation errors could occur on some databases.
>
> The migration to timestamp with time zone might require a migration
> expression like cast(old as timestamp with time zone).
>
> To retain backwards compatibility, configure the setting
> hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type to TIMESTAMP.

Got the same issue with hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type and Instant type.

Any suggesions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like because we are using function hibernate has a problem to define correct return type. It is always returns java.Object. Solutions worked for me:

```
cast(now_utc() as timestamp)
```